# Stack two divs and slide one after another is removed w/jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div (div1) that is position in the bottom-right corner. When div1 is clicked it is removed with jQuery.

I would like to position another div (div2) right over div1 and after the first div is removed, I want the second div slide down, where the first one used to be.

Here's my [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7VgLh/2/).

Comment: You need to use jquery animate method to slide

Comment: You can call the slideDown function after your fadeOut is finished, just add it like you call fadeOut after clicking the div.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this :

```
$(function() {
    $(".div2").css({
        // places .div2 right above .div1
        bottom: $(".div1").outerHeight() + "px"
    });
    $(".div1").click(function() {
        $(".div1").fadeOut("slow", function() {
            $(this).remove();
            $(".div2").animate({
                bottom: "0px" // slides .div2 down
            });
        });
    });
}
```

[**jsFiddle example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/7VgLh/5/)

Comment: Hmm, it didn't quite work for me. I can't seem to see div2 at all... Div2 should always be there. In some instances there may even not be div1 at all, but if it is div 2 needs to be positioned right above it.

Comment: That's weird, I've just tried with FF4, Chrome 11 and IE7, and I can see .div2 with all of them. What browser are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Um... I'm not totally clear on your question, but is this what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/X7XVa/

Comment: Div2 should always be there. In some instances there may even not be div1 at all, but if it is div 2 needs to be positioned right above it.

Answer (score 0):

If #div2 doesn't exist yet:

```
$('#div1').slideUp(300, function(){
    $(this).before('<div id="div2">Content</div>');
    $(this).remove();

    $('#div2').slideDown(300);
});
```

Or, if you already have #div2 on the page:

```
$('#div1').slideUp(300, function(){
    $(this).before('#div2');
    $(this).remove();

    $('#div2').slideDown(300);
});
```